# Example of rxjs5 Combination in javascript

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Hy all, im have ask about Combination Operators from rxjs...

i have array of sites:

```
const sites = [
    { name:'siteOne', url: 'http://www.example.com' },
    { name:'siteTwo', url: 'http://www.google.com' },
    { name:'siteThree', url: 'http://www.google.com' }
    ]
```

So, i don't want make request every time, but i need make one request per site url, than make new stream, combined with sites, like this:

```
[ html, siteTwo, siteThree]
[ html, siteOne ]
```

Any way accomplish this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only fetch the data once per unique url you can do something like this:

```
Rx.Observable.from(sites)
  .groupBy(s => s.url)
  .flatMap(grp => grp.toArray())
  .flatMap(
    uniqueUrlGrouping => fetchHtml(uniqueUrlGrouping[0].url),
    (uniqueUrlGrouping, html) => ({ 
       url: uniqueUrlGrouping[0].url, 
       sites: uniqueUrlGrouping.map(s => s.name), 
       html:html
    })
  )
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Note; for the `toArray()` to work your input stream needs to be completed, otherwise it does not know when it can convert the completed grouped emissions to an array.

Note that the `.groupBy()` will keep all unique urls in memory until your input stream completes so it might grow to a large memory usage if your input stream is unbounded.

Comment: thank you! thats a nice example how  to use of projection function